# Android - retrofit 2 - canot resolve RxJava2CallAdapterFactory

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm using retrofit 2 and rxjava 2 in my application. These are my gradle implementations:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.4.0'

implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
```

This is my API connection class:

```
public class ApiConnection {
  private static String BaseUrl = "http://mysites.com/";
  private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

  public static Retrofit getClient() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
      .setLenient()
      .create();

    if (retrofit == null) {
      retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
  }
}
```

I got an error on this line :

```
RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
```

This is the error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct import is `implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0"` (note the use of rxjava2)